# HTML structure for day by day calendar displaying date ranges

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I've been asked to structure a user interface that will display "Projects" like the table mockup below. (Date on left, projects laid out by date range on the right)

I will start with a data set that follows this pattern (the actual data will have unique ID's, but to keep it simple:

```
2023-12-08, Project C
2023-12-09, Project A, Project C
...and so on
```

I am fine with writing some logic to group projects together, and derive a date range.

**However I'm a bit stuck with how to structure the HTML for this UI.**

I am using Material UI within react, however I want to get back to basics here because I'm a little tripped up by something that feels like it should be super simple!

I created a mockup. Requirements are:

- Dates without any entries should still be displayed.
- There could be 0, 1, 2, 3 projects at once, probably not more than that.
- The "Project" element should be clickable and possible to target for styling/hover etc.

[image: A user interface mockup with dates on the left and projects on the right, where projects shows a colourful representation of three different projects]